# Erro na passagem do Json

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter

Bom dia Guys,

Estou com um erro na leitura de array do meu json quando chamo ele no meu ajax.

Meu json:

```
[{"id":"7","nome":"Anderson","sobrenome":"Dorea"},{"id":"6","nome":"Diego ","sobrenome":"Andrade"},{"id":"8","nome":"Marcelo","sobrenome":"Cordova"}]
```

Minha função ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'package/getUser',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(data[i]);

        }
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Meu controller:

```
function getUser()
{  

    $this->load->model('packageModel');
    $query = $this->packageModel->getUser()->result_array();

     echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Ele não passa array por array... ele separa cada letra quando coloco dentro do meu for, porem preciso jogar essas informações numa div com o append, só que quando faço isso elas saem como undefined. Alguém que possa me dar uma luz?

Comment: Experimente colocar antes do `for`: `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Funcionou, agora por que isso acontece? Tenho outras funções nesse mesmo padrão de captura e não precisei fazer o JSON.parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você usou a sintaxe errada na linha:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

O correto é *camelCase*:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Como a sintaxe está errada, o retorno vem como string normal, e não como um objeto JSON que é parseado pelo `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Caracaaaa, não observei isso! Genial sua análise amigo, parabéns.